# jquery: How to target a class name stored in a variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find out the class name from a check box on click and use that to get all checkbox id's for that class.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var $checkbox_class=$(this).attr('class');
    var check_list = $("'.'+checkbox_class:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get().join('|')
    alert(check_list);
}
if (check_list = "") 
    var check_list="none-selected";
```

How do I target a class name stored in a variable ?

Comment: Use `$('.' + $checkbox_class + ':checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate like this:

```
var $checkbox_class = $(this).attr('class');
var check_list = $('.'+$checkbox_class+':checked').map(function(){
return $(this).attr('id');
}).get().join('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @satpal. This one works:

```
$('.' + $checkbox_class + ':checked')
```

Comment: same answer will provided by Anoop and me

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var $checkbox_class = $(this).attr('class');
    var check_list = $("." + $checkbox_class + ":checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get().join('|')
    alert(check_list);
    if (check_list = "") var check_list = "none-selected";
});
```